# Phonegap/Cordova app launching Google Maps for Navigation

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, cordova, phonegap

I am making an app in Phonegap that needs to launch google maps app and start navigation from the user's current location to a location passed in by the app.

Currently what I'm using is

```
window.open("google.navigation:q="+latitude+","+longitude+"&mode=d" , '_system');
```

Where latitude and longitude are global variables that exist with proper value at the time of execution of this code.

In the PhoneGap mobile app, when I preview this app, executing this code perfectly does the job, opening  maps and starting navigation from the current location to the location passed in.

However when I compile this to an apk and install on the same device, this code does nothing at all.

I have both

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="google.navigation:*" />
```

In my config.xml file.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You may also need to whitelist it in the [Content Security Policy](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#content-security-policy)